# Connect Hometheater to laptop

Tags: laptop, system-sounds, surround-sound, 5.1, home-theater

I have a 5.1 home theater with the ports as the figure shows. How can I connect it to my laptop?
[image]

**Edit**

I have only this cable. I think this is for input1. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to buy an RCA to headphone adapter, and you normal RCA cable.
These can be bought in common electronics stores - ask around your area.

Refer to the diagram below how to connect.
One end is connected to your laptop audio port.
The other end is where the RCA cable is connected to the adapter, then to your speaker.
Connect the RCA cable to the red/white port in your speaker

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am little bit confused. In input 2, I have 3 port. How do I connect it with your photo adapter? So I have to buy 2 cable? One for RCA which will connect from Input2 to your shown adapter?

Comment: I know it is a bit too late for a reply, but hope this diagram helps. For the RCA cable to speaker - cable connections, you may have to play around to get the correct pair connected.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a **HDMI** port on your laptop you can use a Male HDMI to AV Cable they're normally around $5-15 and look like this [image: HDMI to AV]

Failing that you should have a VGA port which will be a VGA to AV Cable that looks like this
[image]

Once they're connected it will act like another Monitor to your laptop for you to display the content you would like on the hometheater

Comment: so the 3 cables goes into Input2 and HDMI/VGA goes to my laptop, right?

Comment: I believe the 3 cables go into their colored port in Input 1 and you're correct about the HDMI/VGA

Comment: hi, did you mean input1 or input2? Input1 has just one port, input2 has three ports.

Comment: I would say Input 2 if it had 3 ports of different colour

Answer (score -1):

Depending on you laptop and if you are a using a docking station, your best option is to use a 3.5mm headphone plug to RCA adapter like this [cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019D048XC) or this [plug](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018V7GTNK).

Be aware you are not going to get your beautiful surround sound as your source is only left and right channel.
You're going to need a 5.1 adapter like this from [Creative Labs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EZT7RE4).

BTW I would avoid the VGA to Audio connection; VGA connection is a video only connetion; and would not have any audio signals connected to it.

These items are from Amazon, but you don't have to buy from them. Just use them as a guide.

Comment: hi there, could you tell me where to connect this cable (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B019D048XC/?tag=stackoverflow17-20). To which ports in my photos above will connect the RCA cables.

Comment: red cable goes to the red port... white cable to white port...
the 3.5mm goes to your headphones