# Home theater connection with laptop audio port

Tags: laptop, surround-sound, 5.1, home-theater, rca

I have an old home theater(HT) with 3 sets of input ports (see photo below). [image]

Now my asus genbook has a 3.5mm audio port. I want to connect audio with my laptop and HT. Just want to use the HT as speaker so that when I play music or movies laptop audio outputs through HT. There is no bluetooth with the HT as well.

I found several solutions that recommend to use 2 RCA to 3.5mm. Something like this.

[image]

My question is where do I connect the two heads of the ports from HT photo? I guess head 1 goes to the laptop audio port.

All I want just to output the sound of my laptop to HT.

Also, is there any other simple solution?

Comment: So changed it for laptop, hope this is okay now.

Comment: You can buy a USB to surround sound converter

Comment: Try plugging your RCA plugs into the red & white or red & black jacks of port 3. Alternately, it looks like the Input 1 ports are 3.5 mm jacks. You may only need a 3.5 mm male to male cable to connect your laptop to *one* of those top ports.

Comment: It appears you asked this same question two days before this at https://superuser.com/questions/1353648/connect-hometheater-to-laptop and received answers there.